# What MongoDB data model to use for this situation? List of users with tags. Get list of all different tags

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

I have a data model in which the user checks-in in the server, sending his ID with a lists of tags he has applied. For example:

```
- User: 1, Tags: "ios8.1", "v1.1", "location_enabled", "likes_pizza"
- User: 2, Tags: "android5.0", "v1.1", "location_disabled", "likes_pizza"
```

It is expected to have millions of concurrent writes (millions of mobile devices sending their tags so I need a highly scalable database).

On the other hand, I have a web panel showing the list of all different tags, and it should show the number of users having each tag. In this example:

```
- "ios8.1" = 1 user
- "android5.0" = 1 user
- "v1.1" = 2 users
- "location_enabled" = 1 user
- "location_disabled" = 1 user
- "likes_pizza" = 2 users
```

The web panel also should allow to query the list of users having for example tags "v1.1" AND "location_enabled"

Which data model should I use? Is it ok to use MongoDB or would it be better to use other database engine?

I have thought several options:

1) The document/table structure for Users is: ID, Other user fields. I have another document/table with Tags: ID, Tag_name. And finally I have a table that relates both: ID_user, ID_Tag. This is the typical relational database structure. Each time a user writes its new tags, I would have to delete all entries in the User_Tags table for that user, find all tag IDs in the Tags table, and create new relations in the User_Tags table..... But that seems kind of a lot of work for each user query. I am using this database model with MySQL and I have a lot of concurrency problems, like requests being discarded because database is locked.

2) The document for User has the array of tags: ID, Tags:[...]. When a Users updates his tags, it just overrides the tags array..... But then I don't know how to efficiently get the list of different tags to show in the web panel.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely solution 2 and aggregation pipelines http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#aggregate